# Im getting finished with non-zero exit value 1 with Gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When I build my Java project with Gradle build, I'm getting `Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1` error.

How to fix this issue.
I'm using Gradle 6.5 with Java 11 with IntelliJ IDE

Comment: Are you sure this is when you build your project, and not when you run the application? In any case, you need to provide more information to us. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question with more context.

Comment: @BjørnVester I'm getting the same error while running the application. Could you please help me how can I resolve it? Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @SwetaSharma: Try running with `-is` (information and stack traces) and look at the output before the error happens. Usually this happens because the application itself fails, and not because of a problem in Gradle itself (though that is also a possibility of cause).